# Having Issues Where In Trying To Change My Chrome Set Priority Form Low to High But It Won't Switch?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, cmd.exe

Either all of the priorities for chrome are Low or Very low

See Picture Below

[image: Task Manager]
I've also viewed another thread on this topic where they use: start "" /high "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" which is exactly the same as mine however as stated before the priorities still won't change and cmd only open's up a new tab. im not entirely sure if that's suppose to happen or if the simple fix is do it once and reset my pc but all i need Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Power Usage" is an indication of CPU time used and is a rough indication of how much electrical or battery power the task *has used in the past*. It has nothing to do with task priority or crashing behaviour.

You cannot set Power Usage.

If you want to change priorities then you will need to go to the "Details" tab in task manager and change them there. This will not magically make the power usage go up though, it will just put those processes above others.